# How I find or enable google mirror service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-mirror-api

I want to develop Google Glass Apps, so I need to activate Google Mirror API, but I couldn't find the API in google  Services.

How I find or enable this service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a Glass device to develop for Google Glass and activate the Google Mirror API.

If you are a Glass Explorer, you should be able to go to the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and select the Services page

[image: Services page]

Scroll down a ways until you get to the Google Mirror API

[image: Google Mirror API switch]

If you do not see this setting, it means you're not whitelisted for the API. This can be due to one of the following reasons:

1. You're not actually a Glass Explorer. In this case, you can't yet develop for Glass unless you are working with someone who does have a device and can permit you to their project.
2. You are a Glass Explorer, but the account you're using for the API Console isn't the same one registered with Glass.
3. Your account wasn't whitelisted.

If either (2) or (3) are true, you should contact a Glass Guide using either the email or phone number provided you, give them your unique ID, and ask to be placed on the developer whitelist.